# Batch download PDF using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, pdf, batch-processing

I'm trying to use Python to batch download PDF's. The process of manually downloading the files are:

1. Open https://www.ffiec.gov/nicpubweb/nicweb/HCSGreaterThan10B.aspx
2. Click on any bank on the list. Let's say I pick the first one, ***JP Morgan***.
3. Click ***Create Report*** for the ***4th*** report from the top (i.e., 
   *Banking Organization Systemic Risk Report (FR Y-15)*)
4. Click ***Your request for a financial report is ready***
5. Download the PDF that opens up with the following url https://www.ffiec.gov/nicpubweb/NICDataCache/FRY15/FRY15_1039502_20160630.PDF
6. Repeat this process for every bank on the list

To download the PDF for JP Morgan, my code is as follows

```
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.ffiec.gov/nicpubweb/NICDataCache/FRY15/FRY15_1039502_20160630.PDF'
res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open('jpm.pdf', 'wb') as handle:
    handle.write(res.read())
```

The code works on my machine but not on someone else's. I suspect this has to do with the ***NICDataCache*** part of the url. I've been to this url so the code knows where to grab the PDF; for someone who hasn't been to the site, if they punch in the above url, they get

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I can try to have Python simulate the button-clicking above and then download the PDF that opens up but was wondering if there's an easier way to do this -- a way that doesn't require me to visit every single url I want to download from. Thanks.

Comment: Try with [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the list of banks, notice the integer in parentheses.

#### Assumption: that integer uniquely identifies that bank.

This is the url that creates the cached resource for you to access:

`https://www.ffiec.gov/nicpubweb/nicweb/FinancialReport.aspx?parID_RSSD={bank_id}&parDT=20160630&parRptType=FRY15`

Notice the `{bank_id}` in the URL. I put that there. If you substitute any of the given integers wrapped in parens from the list of banks, it will generate the cached resource.

Then, if you visit this URL: `https://www.ffiec.gov/nicpubweb/NICDataCache/FRY15/FRY15_{bank_id}_20160630.PDF`

It will respond with the PDF for that bank.

Essentially, you need to go through the list of banks from the first page, generating the cached resource for each bank that you want (by using the first URL as a template, injecting the bank number), then you pull PDFs from the second URL template.

Comment: Is there a way to load the cached resources "silently" in the background? I can do webbrowser.open(cached_resource_url) for each bank but this will open up a bunch of browser tabs. Thanks.